# C++ How to modify spacing when using the same function

Tags: c++

Suppose I have two functions that each use a function `printInfo()` like this:

```
void printInfo() {
    cout << "4spaceshere " << "name";
}

void printMemberInfo() {
    printInfo();
}

void printMember() {
    printInfo();
}

int main() {
    printMemberInfo();
    printMember();

    return 0;
}
```

Is there anyway that I can modify the spaces before `"name"` for each function?

For Example:
`printMemberInfo()` will have to produce output like this: `3spaceshere name`,
And `printInfo()` will print out `5spaceshere name`. I tried `cout << setw()` and `cout.width()` but don't seem to work. Hope you guys can help! Thank you!

Comment: Use function arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a parameter to let `printInfo` know of the number of spaces to print:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void printInfo(int spaces)
{
    std::cout << std::setw(spaces) << ' ' << "name\n";
}

void printMemberInfo()
{
    printInfo(5);
}

void printMember()
{
    printInfo(3);
}

int main()
{
    printMemberInfo();
    printMember();
}
```

or have the calling functions print the spaces required:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void printInfo(int spaces)
{
    std::cout << "name\n";
}

void printMemberInfo()
{
    std::cout << std::setw(5) << ' ';
    printInfo();
}

void printMember()
{
    std::cout << std::setw(3) << ' ';
    printInfo();
}

int main()
{
    printMemberInfo();
    printMember();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes... Here is one way:

```
int printInfo(int nSpaces) {
    for(int j = 0; j < nSpaces; j++)
         cout << ' ';

    cout << name;
}
```

Then calling it:

```
 printInfo(1);  // one space
 printInfo(4);  // four spaces
```

You need to learn how to pass arguments to function if you don't know how.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate your help :)